# Comparable playing cards

Tags: c++, playing-cards

I have written a working implementation of a Poker card that I want to be comparable. I feel that my solution is somewhat bloated in C++, and want to ask if I should have done something different to make it more concise.

```
#ifndef POKER_CARD_H
#define POKER_CARD_H

enum Value { Two, Three, Four, Five, Six, Seven, Eight, Nine, Ten, Jack, Queen, King, Ace};
enum Color {Hearts, Spades, Dimonds, Clubs};

namespace {
    int as_int(Value value){
        switch(value){
            case Value::Two     : return 2;
            case Value::Three   : return 3;
            case Value::Four    : return 4;
            case Value::Five    : return 5;
            case Value::Six     : return 6;
            case Value::Seven   : return 7;
            case Value::Eight   : return 8;
            case Value::Nine    : return 9;
            case Value::Ten     : return 10;
            case Value::Jack    : return 11;
            case Value::Queen   : return 12;
            case Value::King    : return 13;
            case Value::Ace     : return 14;
        }
    }
    int as_int(Color color){
        switch(color){
            case Color::Dimonds : return 1;
            case Color::Clubs   : return 2;
            case Color::Hearts  : return 3;
            case Color::Spades  : return 4;
        }
    }
}

class Card {

public:
    Card(Value value, Color color);

    Color getColor() const;

    Value getValue() const;

private:
    Value value;
    Color color;
};

inline bool operator==(const Card& lhs, const Card& rhs) {
    return ((rhs.getValue() == lhs.getValue()) && (rhs.getColor() == lhs.getColor()));
}
inline bool operator!=(const Card& lhs, const Card& rhs) {return !operator==(lhs,rhs);}
inline bool operator< (const Card& lhs, const Card& rhs) {
    if (as_int(lhs.getValue()) < as_int(rhs.getValue())){
        return true;
    }
    else if (as_int(rhs.getValue()) == as_int(lhs.getValue())){
        return as_int(lhs.getColor()) < as_int(rhs.getColor()) ? true : false;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
inline bool operator> (const Card& lhs, const Card& rhs) {return  operator< (rhs,lhs);}
inline bool operator<=(const Card& lhs, const Card& rhs) {return !operator> (lhs,rhs);}
inline bool operator>=(const Card& lhs, const Card& rhs) {return !operator< (lhs,rhs);}


#endif //POKER_CARD_H
```

Comment: Are there any restrictions as to which version of the standard you can use?

Comment: your as_int methods can be a **lot** shorter. You will have to reorder the enum for sutes though. You can convert the enum to an integer, then add one.

Comment: Use of get in method names reduces readability. A method returning  a not boolean should be a noun phrase, and if returning a boolean should be an adjective phrase. Expections: if where you live people say “What is the get colour?“ or “would you like get fries with that?”.

Comment: Are you sure you need conversion from enum to int? That's fine to compare enums, not ints.

Comment: We normally use the word "suit" (normal cards come in two colours - black for Spades and Clubs, red for Hearts and Diamonds - though some poker sets have green Clubs and blue Diamonds).

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor Comments are for seeking clarification to the question, and may be deleted. Please put all suggestions for improvements in answers, even if your answer is brief.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Plain `enum` (unlike `enum class`) convert implicitly to integers, so there's no need for the `as_int()` functions if you declare the enums in ascending order.  You probably want the suits in the order ♣♦♥♠ if you want to re-use your cards for Bridge as well as Poker.

I had to make up the constructor and `get` methods, since they are missing from the review:

```
Card(Value value, Color color)
    : value{value},
      color{color}
{}

Color getColor() const { return color; };

Value getValue() const { return value; };
```

I also created a simple test program that returns non-zero if we break the expectations:

```
int main()
{
    return
        + (Card{Two, Clubs} > Card{Ace, Spades})
        + (Card{Two, Clubs} > Card{Two, Spades})
        + (Card{Two, Spades} > Card{Ace, Spades});
}
```

Now, we can remove the `as_int()`:

```
enum Value { Two, Three, Four, Five, Six, Seven, Eight, Nine, Ten, Jack, Queen, King, Ace};
enum Color { Clubs, Dimonds, Hearts, Spades};
```

```
inline bool operator==(const Card& lhs, const Card& rhs)
{
    return rhs.getValue() == lhs.getValue()
        && rhs.getColor() == lhs.getColor();
}

inline bool operator!=(const Card& lhs, const Card& rhs) { return !(lhs==rhs); }

inline bool operator< (const Card& lhs, const Card& rhs)
{
    if (lhs.getValue() < rhs.getValue()) {
        return true;
    }
    else if (rhs.getValue() == lhs.getValue()) {
        return lhs.getColor() < rhs.getColor() ? true : false;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}

inline bool operator> (const Card& lhs, const Card& rhs) {return rhs < lhs;}
inline bool operator<=(const Card& lhs, const Card& rhs) {return !(lhs>rhs);}
inline bool operator>=(const Card& lhs, const Card& rhs) {return !(lhs<rhs);}
```

Note that this ternary conditional:

```
        return lhs.getColor() < rhs.getColor() ? true : false;
```

is exactly equivalent to this:

```
        return lhs.getColor() < rhs.getColor();
```

But we can simplify the `<` much further by delegating to `std::tuple`:

```
inline bool operator< (const Card& lhs, const Card& rhs) {
    return std::tuple(lhs.getValue(), lhs.getColor()) < std::tuple(rhs.getValue(), rhs.getColor());
}
```

In C++20, the entire set of 6 comparisons [can be replaced](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0515r3.pdf) with a single function:

```
public:
    auto operator<=>(const Card&) const = default;
```

Comment: This has been very insightful thank you very much!

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to translate your `Card`s into `int`s to compare them.

Keep your scoped enumerations, it's a good practice. Then all you need to write is:

```
using Card = std::pair<Value, Color>;
```

because `std::pair` already has an overload of the comparison operators relying on the lexicographical order:

```
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>

enum class Value {Two, Three, Four, Five, Six, Seven, Eight, Nine, Ten, Jack, Queen, King, Ace};
enum class Color {Hearts, Spades, Dimonds, Clubs};

int main() {

    using Card = std::pair<Value, Color>;
    Card a{Value::Six, Color::Hearts}, b{Value::Six, Color::Clubs};
    bool test = a < b;
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << test; // true
}
```

Comment: The downside of using `std::pair` is that the data members are now called `first` and `second` instead of `value` and `suit`, and they are now publicly-writable.

Comment: Publicly writable isn't really a downside since the preconditions are enforced by the `enum`. You can't make up a "15 of hearts". `first` and `second`, I agree, is less beautiful, but again `enum class` prevents accidental switches so any error would be catched early and clearly.

Comment: It might be a bad thing if you can change the ♥2 in your hand to a ♥A when you need it; my assumption from the original code was that it was intended as an immutable type.   ...<Thinks>  `std::pair<const Value, const Color>` should be fine, though.

Comment: I agree with you about the rough edges of that solution, but what a gain in maintenance and coding time!

Comment: Agreed - that's definitely a good review, and you've received my vote.  :-)

Answer (score 4):

First if you are going to use `lhs` and `rhs` then I expect to read them on the left and right hand sides respectively (unless switching them was inherent like overloading `operator>` in terms of `operator<`).

**Your switches are unnecessary**

In C++, enums implicitly convert to int. If you wanted to change the underlying type you can. You can also assign a value to an individual enum and the rest will increment from there. Like so:

```
enum Value : unsigned { Two = 2, Three, Four, Five, Six, Seven, Eight, Nine, Ten, Jack, Queen, King, Ace };
enum Color { Hearts = 1, Spades, Dimonds, Clubs };
```

Now if you switched to [enum class](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum), which might be a good idea it will require the use of casts to make conversions (then if you want to overload your operators to keep your casts in one place that might be nice).